# WebSockets - Ratchet (Thruway)

Tags: javascript, websocket, ratchet, handshake, thruway

I have a problem when connecting to websocket server when using Chrome on OSX.

- We use this package: https://github.com/voryx/Thruway
- I test it here: http://websocket.org/echo.html
- Address to the server is: `wss://dev.unisim.cz:4444`

If I try to connect to server using Firefox it works well but if I use Chrome there is an error message:

> Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 302.

Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: It works in my chrome, however, I'm running win 10. Two questions for you: does the page actually say to you: "This browser supports WebSocket."? And have you inspected the network tab in chrome debug tools and compared it with network traffic from firebug?

Comment: Yes it is very strange situation. On the most devices and browsers it work but for my newest osx and chrome it doesn't. We tested it with 3 mac devices with chrome and it doesn't work anywhere. As you can see from screen: https://www.dropbox.com/s/b5uol7cqa09hder/Screenshot%202016-11-15%2016.18.12.png?dl=0

Comment: can you please show also the request and response headers? and does this also happen from within anonymous mode?

Comment: here is .har content where is everything i can show you http://pastebin.com/5QkVBP6A

Comment: It is the same in anonymous window. Here is some test urls: ws:
ws://dev.unisim.cz:8888/

wws - NGINX SSL proxy on port 4444:
wss://dev.unisim.cz:4444/

wws -  Apache SSL proxy on port 443:
wss://ws.dev.unisim.cz/

Answer (score 0):

Thruway is actually a WAMPv2 router and client (allows RPC and pub/sub patterns), not raw websockets as the websocket.org echo test is expecting. I am not sure why it would allow anything in either browser.

If you are looking for raw websocket communication with PHP, check out https://github.com/ratchetphp/Ratchet and https://github.com/ratchetphp/Pawl (Thruway uses these libraries for websocket related tasks.)

Comment: We are not looking for raw websockets. We would like to use pub/sub patterns but websockets.org was one of online testing software which replicate the same status/error.

Comment: The issue is that when you try to connect to a Thruway router, it expects the client to be using the wamp.2.json subprotocol. If you connect with raw websockets, it will refuse to upgrade the connection. If you are looking into the browser side, you will need a WAMP client like autobahn js

Comment: I'm sorry i gave you bad example to test online. We are using exact autobahn js.